# How exacly do you use the -z option for the "cut" command?

Tags: unix, cut

In the documentation it says that the `-z` option changes the default line delimiter, which is a newline character, to ASCII NUL. How exactly do you use that option? Take a look at this example please (the file is tab-separated):

```
$ cat data.tsv 
John Doe    28  New York
Bob Smith   37  Boston
Jane Doe    31  Boston
$
$ cut -f1,3 data.tsv 
John Doe    New York
Bob Smith   Boston
Jane Doe    Boston
$
$ # This is the output I get:
$ cut -f1,3 -z data.tsv 
John Doe    New York
Bob Smith$
```

I can't make sense of that output. What exactly is going on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-z` is for when your *input* is NUL-delimited instead of `\n`-delimited. It changes how `cut` processes the the input, and also makes it output records in the same format, with `\0` line endings.

Your input data now is:

```
John Doe    28  New York\nBob Smith   37  Boston\nJane Doe    31  Boston\n
```

If it had NULs instead of newlines, you'd use `-z`:

```
John Doe    28  New York\0Bob Smith   37  Boston\0Jane Doe    31  Boston\0
```

When would this be useful? It's not for files as much as it is for pipelines. For instance, you could use `find -print0` to output file names with `\0` after each name. `find -print0` allows you to process file names with embedded newlines—it is highly unusual, but newlines are legal characters in file names. `\0` is never legal.

Then `cut -z` would be useful.

Similar flags in other commands include `xargs -0`, `read -d ''`, and `cpio -0`.

Answer (score 1):

The **ASCII `NULL` character is in fact the End-of-File**. Your input file actually contains:

```
John Doe\t28\tNew York\n
Bob Smith\t37\tBoston\n
Jane Doe\t31\tBoston\n
\0
```

(`\n` is the new line, `\0` is the ASCII `NULL`, `\t` is a tab).

If your line delimiter is the end-of-file, then the first field  will be "John Doe" (which is what you expected) and the third field is "`New York\nBob Smith`". The `\n` is not a field separator here, so the field runs up to the next tab.